# Bibliography unicode char \u8 error

Tags: bibliographies

I changed and then changed back my bibliography list. It worked till the point of changes, and now it won't compile even with an empty bibliography. My document is following

```
\documentclass[a4paper, leqno, oneside] {report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[swedish, english]{babel}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[textwidth=15cm, textheight=23cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{rotating,caption,booktabs}

\begin{document}   
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} %{amsplain}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\include{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

with Bibliography.tex being

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{book1}
A title \textit{Pensionsmyndigheten}

\end{thebibliography}
```

Why has it stopped working? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Please help us help you by removing all unnecessary packages from your MWE and integrating your separate file into the main file.

Comment: Why do you have both `\bibliography{Bibliography}` and `\include{Bibliography}`? Do you actually want two bibliographies (one generated by `bibtex` and the other generated manually)?

Comment: I removed either \bibliography{Bibliography} and \include{Bibliography} and still doesn't work.